# How is g(x) a surjection in Thomas Jech's proof of Cantor-Bernstein's theorem?

Tags: elementary-set-theory

Page 28 of Set Theory by Thomas Jech states a proof of the theorem:
Let $f_1:A\mapsto B$ and $f_2:B\mapsto A$ denote the injections. Let $B'=f_2(B)$ and $A'=f_2(f_1(A))$. Clearly, $|A'|=|A|$ and $|B'|=|B|$, now we may assume that $A'\subset B\subset A$. Let$f$ now denote the bijection $A\mapsto A'$.\
We define by induction: $$A_0=A,A_{n+1}=f(A_n),B_0=B, B_{n+1}=f(B_n).$$
Now let $g(x)=f(x)$ if $x\in A_n-B_n$ for some $n$, or $g(x)=x$ otherwise.
I personally have no trouble seeing g as an injection. However, I cannot comprehend how it is also a surjection. Specifically, certainly $x\in im(g(x))$ if $x\in A_{n+1}-B_{n+1}$ for some n, and certainly also $x\in im(g(x))$ if $x \notin A_{n}-B_{n}$ for any n. However, what about the case of elements in $A_0-B_0$? Which elements in $A$ gets mapped to those?

Comment: What exactly is the role that $g$ is meant to fill in the proof?

Comment: @Arthur g is supposed to be the bijection between A and B. Sorry, apparently I made a stupid mistake.

Answer (score 1):

Apparently I was confusing myself regardind the definitions of $g$.... We don't  need to find elements that get mapped to elements in $A-B$, because $A-B$ is not supposed to be in the range of $g$, since $g$ is a bijection $A\mapsto B$.